# 2D game engine for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am searching for a 2D game engine for iPhone and iPad.  Who has a experience in this field?

What is the engine running Angry Birds?

Answer (score 5):

I'd recommend Cocos 2D. However, you could use Unity for 2D games if you wanted, though it is designed with 3D games in mind. If you are more of a hobbyist, iTorque 2D is fun to play with.

Also, I believe that Angry Birds was built using the Box 2D physics engine but has a custom game engine written by good people over at Rovio.

Answer (score 2):

If you know C++ then try [Oxygine](http://oxygine.org).
 [image]

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the emo framework: http://code.google.com/p/emo-framework/
It's not widely known yet, but it's a really powerful, wonderful, really beautiful framework. It's free and works on iOS and Android.

As far as Rovio and Angry Birds is concerned I also believe they use their own game engine, which uses Box2D as the physics engine http://box2d.org - this is a known fact, they were listed as Box2D users on Box2D website in the past, although I cannot find it right now. Box2D is used by many engines, including emo framework.